# How register Hibernate naming strategy?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

I overrided all ImprovedNamingStrategy methods and placed for them breakpoints,
but methods were not called in debug mode.

I have only one hibernate factory, so mistake because of other instance is impossible.

I think, the problem is in the key "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" or no?

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">com.stub.utilities.dao.sql.hibernate.LowerCaseNamingStrategy
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    //..
    public class LowerCaseNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {
```

Comment: We need more details of your environment, are you using plain hibernate or spring data jpa or plain JPA (with hibernate as implementation - are you using EntityManager)